# Questions about site I built show up before the actual site in Google search

Tags: support, google

I created a website for a friend of mine.

I asked several questions regarding the website on Stack Overflow. When searching for the website using Google, the questions are ranked higher than the site I built!

Is there a way I can hide these questions from search engines? I don't want to delete them, as the answers are useful for me and anyone else. I just want the actual web site to show up before the questions about it.

Comment: If they have any upvoted answers, you can't delete them.

Comment: No you cannot hide them from the search engines.

Comment: Also - why is this a problem? We all had/have to learn stuff, we are not born with it in our heads.

Comment: How are they being found? Do you have links to the site in those posts? Because you could probably just remove the links. Upload images with the built-in feature so they don't use that domain, anonymize the site, make sure all the code is here on Stack Overflow rather than linking to it wherever.

Comment: I don't see them on top, beware that you might be getting personalized Google results.  One thing you can do is post the images to Imgur and edit the links in your question.

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't edit any mentions of the company out of your questions?

Comment: Get into the habit of anonymising any code you post on Stack Overflow. It's just good practice privacy-wise, and usually makes questions easier to understand anyway.

Comment: @NickODell this

Comment: I don't see this as a bad question; you can interpret it as a crap "delete my stuff for me kthx" questions (downvote away) or as a question about how to break the link between his questions and the website.  That's perfectly fine and understandable in general, as SO results may be ranked higher than the subject webpage.

Comment: Definitely agreed with @Will's reading; the title was problematic here in that it made the post look like "oh, crap, my boss is going to find out that I don't know what I'm doing". Hopefully my edit fixes that.

Answer (score 8):

No.  When you posted the question to SE you implicitly consented to the content being licences under the CC-Wiki license.  SE (and everyone else in the world) now has the right to share that content or create derived works from it (so long as there is proper attribution).  You cannot revoke that right.

Answer (score 6):

You can edit your questions to ***replace*** (notice, I didn't say *remove*) references to BollinBuild with a generic name, such as "example website name".

I'd go through all the code examples and replace any static text that might be indexed with "lorem ipsum" boilerplate text.  Also, delete any links to the website, if you have any.  Please note, if you remove elements important to your question, such as layout code (e.g., delete div tags central to your question), this may be seen as vandalism and be reversed.

May not help right away, but will probably help later on as it gets reindexed.